# FASTLOAD ERROR : FDL4822 DEFINE statement rejected

Tags: python, teradata

I am new to teradata fastload. And I want to use it to convert csv file to TD. it seems the DEFINE part has some error.  I've tried to search solutions but failed.Please help me. Thanks!

```
0008         DEFINE
             "seg_beg_loc_dt" (varchar(600)),
     "workitem_id" (varchar(600)),
     "cust_id" (varchar(600)),
     "ivrintent" (varchar(600)),
     "contact_rsn" (varchar(600)),
     "probs" (varchar(600)),
     "check_flag" (varchar(600))

             FILE='/x/home/pp_di_sha_user/Shitohuang/Contact_Intent_Mapping/csv
     /RT_01_ivr_intent_tag2019-03-26
     .txt';          /* specifies the location path for the flat file */

**** 23:34:35 FDL4822 DEFINE statement rejected.
**** 23:34:35 Definition syntax error for: DEFINE
     ===================================================================
     =                                                                 =
     =          Logoff/Disconnect                                      =
     =                                                                 =
     ===================================================================

**** 23:34:35 Logging off all sessions
**** 23:34:36 Total processor time used = '4.99 Seconds'
     .        Start : Sun Apr  7 23:34:20 2019
     .        End   : Sun Apr  7 23:34:36 2019
     .        Highest return code encountered = '8'.
**** 23:34:36 FastLoad Paused
```

here is my define part

```
    DEFINE
        "seg_beg_loc_dt" (varchar(600)),
"workitem_id" (varchar(600)),
"cust_id" (varchar(600)),
"ivrintent" (varchar(600)),
"contact_rsn" (varchar(600)),
"probs" (varchar(600)),
"check_flag" (varchar(600))

        FILE='/x/home/pp_di_sha_user/Shitohuang/Contact_Intent_Mapping/csvRT_01_ivr_intent_tag2019-03-18
.txt';          /* specifies the location path for the flat file */
```

Comment: Strange, your syntax seems ok. Check if there are any non-printable characters, i.e. looks like a space, but is something different.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved this problem,this problem is due to the wrong file dir